# Consumer can't poll from newly created partition until it's restarted

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a `Spring Boot` project that implements `Kafka`. The application uses `producer` to produce a message on a `topic` in a specific `partition`. The `partitions` on the `topic` are made dynamically on run time. After I add a new `partition`, the already running `consumer` for the given `topic` doesn't see this `partition`, but sees the older ones. However, when I restart the `consumer`, `the consumer` starts seeing the new `partition` and starts `polling` successfully from it.

My question is: Can I make this work without restarting the consumer and if I can, how? I can't seem to find this anywhere in the official documentation.

Partition creation:

```
 Map<String,NewPartitions> increaseTopicPartitions = new HashMap<String,NewPartitions>();
            increaseTopicPartitions.put("nodesTopic", NewPartitions.increaseTo(totalPartitions + 1));
            BaseProcessor.adminClient.createPartitions(increaseTopicPartitions);
```

Printing partition count:

```
 int totalPartitions = cluster.partitionCountForTopic(topic);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumer will only see the new partitions when it refreshes its cluster metadata. By default this only happens every 5 mins (see `metadata.max.age.ms` in the [Consumer configurations](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs)).

Once the new partitions are detected, they should be correctly assigned and the consumer should start receiving messages.

Comment: It worked, thank you :)
Is it safe to put the `metadata.max.age.ms` to be 3 seconds?

Comment: With such a short interval, your client will be sending metadata requests to the cluster every 3 seconds. While these requests are relatively light, you don't want 100s of clients all sending metadata requests this often. Also in practice, people usually don't add partitions very often, so having a short delay (~1-5mins) is acceptable